# Difference between view volume/view frustum and Viewport?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

What is the difference in Open GL ES between camera view volume/view frustum vs Viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that explains pretty well..http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsFundamentalsViewport

Here is how I think of it.. even though I don't know much about opengl...

viewport is... similar to window in your house, you will only see what the window allow you to see the outside world... in other words... the world is very big but window only allow you to see small portion of it...

volume/frustrum is.. like the link says... you only see whats bounded by this volume... only the objects inside this volume is rendered..

for example, if you have a train track on your scene.. and you want to animate the train leaving.. technically train could keep on going.. until it becomes a small point and takes up only a pixel or so. But you do not want to do that.. (similar to games).. it fades into a  cloud/dust/hide behind buildings or other objects... that way it doesn't take up so much memory on your computer where user don't care about it anymore..